# How to Show Dialogs Using MVVM Light for WPF?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

I need your help. I already have spent researching for the correct way on how to show dialogs using MVVM Light for WPF. However, I'm out of luck.

I read this about on how to implement/use DialogService: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/dialogservice-in-mvvm-light-v5/ only to find out that it has no DialogService. I have to implement DialogService for WPF.

Can somebody help me on how to implement DialogService for WPF? Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM) I wrote last year on this topic, it shows a way of implementing them that is closer to how regular windows are managed. Also I provide a complete standalone library you can add directly to your project.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I have read this article but this approach needs to create properties for the dialog box to show up and need to declare it as well in the view property. I'm still searching for an answer though.

Comment: It's hard to believe that in 2022, xaml/mvvm still has to write a lot more code to implement a very simple feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a perfect solution but I created a service to show dialog.

```
public interface IDialogService {
    void ShowError(Exception Error, string Title);
    void ShowError(string Message, string Title);
    void ShowInfo(string Message, string Title);
    void ShowMessage(string Message, string Title);
    bool ShowQuestion(string Message, string Title);
    void ShowWarning(string Message, string Title);
}

public class DialogService : IDialogService {
    public void ShowError(Exception Error, string Title) {
        MessageBox.Show(Error.ToString(), Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }

    public void ShowError(string Message, string Title) {
        MessageBox.Show(Message, Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }

    public void ShowInfo(string Message, string Title) {
        MessageBox.Show(Message, Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }

    public void ShowMessage(string Message, string Title) {
        MessageBox.Show(Message, Title, MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }

    public bool ShowQuestion(string Message, string Title) {
        return MessageBox.Show(Message, Title, MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes;
    }

    public void ShowWarning(string Message, string Title) {
        MessageBox.Show(Message, Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    }
}
```

This works fine with me. If there's a need to change on the platform, you can just modify the DialogService class.

Comment: Is it possible to pass the owner of the dialog as paramater?

Comment: I just did it with MVVMLight. Inside of ViewLocator's constructor SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDialogService>(() => new DialogService(Application.Current.MainWindow));